# HTML aside tag: is it OK to use for form error message?

Tags: css, html, error-handling, semantics

So I have a form and I'll have error messages associated with each input/element.
I've come up with this use for the `<aside>` tag and was wondering what people thought:

```
    <section class="fieldrow" id="rowJobTitle">

        <label for="txtJobTitle" id="lblJobTitle">
            <span>Job title:</span>
        </label>

        <input type="text" id="txtJobTitle" name="txtJobTitle">

        <aside id="errJobTitle" class="errormessage">
            <span role="alert">Please tell us your job title.</span>
        </aside>

    </section>
```

Then I'll be using CSS to show or hide the `<aside>` errors with a little JS to change this.

I know I could just use the span, and be done with it, but a span tag has no semantic value, and all the (short and vague) info I've read on `<aside>` seems to say there's no problem with this, but I was hoping that I could either get some confirmation, or someone who's tried this before and found a good reason not to.

Thanks, Si.

Comment: Why not use the title attribute in the input tag? Or a data attribute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<aside>` tag is supported in all major browsers.

There are, however, potentially more elegant ways to do this, and `<aside>` is not particularly semantic for what you mean. [From the HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-aside-element.html):

> The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of
>   content that is tangentially related to the content around the aside
>   element, **and which could be considered separate from that content**.
>   Such sections are often represented as sidebars in printed typography.

Your error is not really separate from the content, so it's a fairly inappropriate choice.

You should look at how [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#forms) does in-line form errors.

All that said, this is *semantics*, and therefore inherently subjective. If it makes sense to you and it works, why not use it?

### EDIT

Upon reading Rob's link, `<aside>` looks even more inappropriate than I thought. Since `<aside>` is not a sub-element of the `<input>`, there is no reason a parser would think it related to that `<input>`. I would avoid its usage in this context.

MDN gives some use cases for this, and yours doesn't fit:

> they often contains side explanation like a glossary definition, more
>   loosely related stuff like advertisements, the biography of the
>   author, or in web-applications, profile information or related blog
>   links.

Comment: The spec may have changed so I need to look at the dates. See my answer and link.

Comment: Not convinced about the Twitter Bootstrap markup either, but the rest of your answer is good. +1

Comment: Yeah, not sure a `<label>` makes perfect sense, but more than `<aside>` IMHO.

Comment: Thanks, Josh... 

I've just updated my original post to add some context.

Comment: Some articles seem to say that `<aside>` is relative either to an article or the entire page... others don't specify this, is there anywhere that says an `<aside>` cannot be related to it's parent `<section>` element, the W3C HTML5 spec says it should be related to the main textual flow of the document [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/aside.html) so I guess perhaps it is a bad use... would you recommend anything else? the Twitter Bootstrap is nice... but I'd like something more semantic... the use of HTML to layout a page is opposite to what I want to achieve. :)

Comment: I think MDN's use cases are telling (and yours doesn't seem so appropriate): `they often contains side explanation like a glossary definition, more loosely related stuff like advertisements, the biography of the author, or in web-applications, profile information or related blog links.` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/aside

Comment: Hmmm, yeh it seems as though the tag is designed for sites with articles (blogs, news, etc) and has no place within a web app form. Unfortunately. I guess with HTML5 Validation they decided separate error messages wern't worth marking up...

I'll leave this going a while longer before I give a tick, meanwhile I'll see if there's any avenues other than `<span>` and perhaps post up my creative use of the `<details>` tag for you to pick over ^_^ Thanks again. Si.

Answer (score 4):

The `<aside>` element is not supported by IE 8 and older. This means that any styles you set on it are lost in those browsers. You can partially work around this by using JavaScript code that “teaches” the element to them, but is this all worth the gain? What exactly is the expected gain?

Logically, the use described does not match the HTML5 semantics. The descriptions there are vague, but I don’t think an error message can be characterized as *tangential* when it is displayed and relevant; it’s really the key content then. It is not *separate* from the rest of the content; instead, it expresses vital information about it.

An advertisement would be a candidate for `<aside>`, and so would an anecdote, or a history note, or generally content that is not necessarily by any means but has some connection with the main content.

I have not seen any evidence of any software such as search engines or browsers or browser add-ons actually making use of `<aside>` markup. Just speculation about what might be done.

I think there’s a fundamental flaw in the overall design, making the question about element semantics even more theoretical. What happens when CSS *or* JavaScript is disabled? Right, the user always sees the error message, even when he has not entered input at all or the input is all correct.

A better approach, assuming that this is about errors detected in *client-side* code, is to keep the error message texts just in JavaScript strings. When an error has been detected, a new element is added, or existing element content is modified, to make an error message available; and it would then be wiped out when the error has been corrected. (No need to rely on CSS here.)

This way, the error message could be placed before the field, on the right of it, or below it. It would not matter much which elements you use for it (search engines won’t see it, and browsers are hardly expected to do anything special with it on their own), but `<div><strong>...</strong></div>` would probably a good choice.

Comment: Good post, I'm going to have to agree now, `<aside>` isn't the right tag to use, I think a plain old `<span>` will have to do. // To answer the question: It's not a bother since I'm using a shiv anyway, and the application is going to be aimed at IE7+ with JS enabled. The only gain is to do things smartly, intuitively and properly. // To answer the follow up: I'll be using server-side to generate and serve the errors via ajax to ease the page load, with fall-backs for non-JS. But that's all aside (hehe) from the main point. :)
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's related to the article, and therefore the context (most important), this should be acceptable. I even think it's a very good use of aside. [See this.](http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/)

**EDIT:** With all the discussion, I'm thinking there is no appropriate, semantic element to do this and the best one to use would be a generic div element. We're trying too hard to force a HTML5 element.